# IHP - How to use multiple collectionFetchRelated?

Tags: ihp

I have the following Comments schema:

```
Table: Comments
Columns: id, post_id, body, user_id, created_at
```

I want to fetch comments with its respective post and user.

Using `collectionFetchRelated` for one column is simple:

```hs
comments <- query @Comment 
  |> fetch
  >>= collectionFetchRelated #postId
```

And it can be easily called by,

```hs
Include "postId" Comment
```

But how to use it and call for multiple columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```hs
comments :: [Include' ["postId", "userId"] Comment] <- query @Comment 
  |> fetch
  >>= collectionFetchRelated #postId
  >>= collectionFetchRelated #userId
```

The [`Include' ["postId", "userId"] Comment`](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/api-docs/IHP-ModelSupport.html#t:Include-39-) type is just a shorthand for `Include "userId" (Include "postId" (Comment))`